# How to calculate sum from a list — Typescript - Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

New in TypeScript — Angular 2.

I wondering to know how to calculate a sum from a list.

I already selected the items needed and get the sum with a error :

> TS Error Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Creance[]',

```
creancesOfSelectedRemise: Creance[];

onSelectRemise(remise: Remise, event: any) {
...//...
this.creancesOfSelectedRemise = this.creances
  .filter(c => c.id_remettant === remise.id_remettant)
  .forEach(c => this.totalCreances += c.creance_montant);
}
```

It seems 'forEach' is not used correctly.

Is it possible to add the filter and the forEach in the same time ?

thanks
Bea

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of using [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) you should use [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to return the numbers you want to sum up, and then use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) to sum them:

```
onSelectRemise(remise: Remise, event: any) {
    ...
    this.creancesOfSelectedRemise = this.creances
        .filter(c => c.id_remettant === remise.id_remettant)
        .map(c => c.creance_montant)
        .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);
}
```

You can remove a cycle of iterations by filtering out the items in the mapping:

```
onSelectRemise(remise: Remise, event: any) {
    ...
    this.creancesOfSelectedRemise = this.creances
        .map(c => c.id_remettant === remise.id_remettant ? c.creance_montant : 0)
        .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current);
}
```

Comment: I know this is old, but couldn't you just to `this.creancesOfSelectedRemise = this.creances.reduce((sum, c) => sum + c.creance_montant, 0);`?

Comment: @Jocie The OP wanted to filter out some elements from the list (based on `remise.id_remettant`). Your solution doesn't seem to take that into account.